# if else statement in the controller not responding in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, if-statement, controller

am trying to prevent a logged in user from accessing some passages exception the user has his information in the NextofKin table by using this method in my controller

```
public function checkValidTenant($tenant_id){
    $check = NextOfKin::where('tenant_id', '=', $tenant_id)->findOrFail('tenant_id');
    return $check;
}
```

While in the method that will display such page, I add the following code for restriction

```
if($this->checkValidTenant(\Auth::user()->id)){
    $rents = RentDue::where('tenant_id', '=', \Auth::user()->id)->get();
    return view('/tenant/rent', compact('rents'));
}else{
    return redirect()->route('tenant/profile');
}
```

I also tried it like this

```
if($this->checkValidTenant(\Auth::user()->id) === true){
    $rents = RentDue::where('tenant_id', '=', \Auth::user()->id)->get();
    return view('/tenant/rent', compact('rents'));
}else{
    return redirect()->route('tenant/profile');
}
```

Here is the route

```
Route::get('rent', 'TenantController@rent');
```

The problem is when I try accessing the page with a logged user that satisfy the condition, it will throw the following error

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
```

But I noticed that this page gets displayed only when I remove this restriction. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Is there `rent` function present in `TenantController`?

Comment: @LovepreetSingh Yes there is rent function in the TenantController

Answer (score 0):

`findOrFail` will throw a 404 when it does not find a record. If you change that part to `get` or `first` you will probably have the desired result.

```
public function checkValidTenant($tenant_id){
    $check = NextOfKin::where('tenant_id', '=', $tenant_id)->first();
    return $check;
}
```

> Sometimes you may wish to throw an exception if a model is not found. This is particularly useful in routes or controllers. The `findOrFail` and `firstOrFail` methods will retrieve the first result of the query; however, if no result is found, a  `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` will be thrown.

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) (scroll down to the 'Not Found Exceptions' part)

Comment: thanks for your response. Tried using get or first but I got the following error instead  Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, string given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dweb/propertyzone/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 131

Comment: @Omotola I need more than that, because I can't figure out where that error is coming from. There are multiple hits on Google and StackOverflow as well with that error. Could be a totally different issue though.

Comment: Have search for a solution as well but non of the solutions offered worked for me. as an addition information, have got 5 pages in the app, once logged in, the user is directed to the profile page, the user is expected to fill a form before he can access the other 4 pages. Having created and linked the pages, they all display fine until I included the if statement. To achieve the restriction, I wrote a method that checks the NextOfKin table to see if there is data on the user using the tenant_id to column. I hope this helps, should I include the table structure

Comment: @Omotola Is there a stacktrace of the error? If so, could you check what part of the code is responsible for this error?